# Choose specific input channel as a mono input from USB device in AVAudioSession/AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I'm working on an audio recording app which uses an external USB Audio interface (e.g, Focusrite Scarlett Solo) connected to an iPhone.

When I run `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.inputs` it returns the interface correctly.

```
1 element
  - 0 : <AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x28307c650, type = USBAudio; name = Scarlett Solo USB; UID = AppleUSBAudioEngine:Focusrite:Scarlett Solo USB:130000:1,2; selectedDataSource = (null)>
```

Channels are returned correctly as well.

```
po AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.inputs.first?.channels
▿ Optional<Array<AVAudioSessionChannelDescription>>
  ▿ some : 2 elements
    - 0 : <AVAudioSessionChannelDescription: 0x283070b60, name = Scarlett Solo USB 1; label = 4294967295 (0xffffffff); number = 1; port UID = AppleUSBAudioEngine:Focusrite:Scarlett Solo USB:130000:1,2>
    - 1 : <AVAudioSessionChannelDescription: 0x283070b70, name = Scarlett Solo USB 2; label = 4294967295 (0xffffffff); number = 2; port UID = AppleUSBAudioEngine:Focusrite:Scarlett Solo USB:130000:1,2>
```

When I connect the `inputNode` to `mainMixerNode` in `AVAudioEngine` it uses multi-channel input so the Line/Instrument input is on the right channel and Microphone input is on the left.

How can I make it so that I use only the 2nd Channel (guitar) as a mono to be played back in both speakers?

I've been looking through some docs and discussions but could not find the answer.

I tried changing channels to 1 in audio format but as expected it plays the first channel in mono but I can't select 2nd channel to be played instead.

```
let input = engine.inputNode
let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
        
let preferredFormat = AVAudioFormat(
    commonFormat: inputFormat.commonFormat,
    sampleRate: inputFormat.sampleRate,
    channels: 1,
    interleaved: false
)!

engine.connect(input, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: preferredFormat)
```

EDIT:
As asked, I'm adding channel mapping code

```
let input = engine.inputNode
let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
        
engine.mainMixerNode.auAudioUnit.channelMap = [1]
engine.connect(input, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputFormat)
```

EDIT 2:

So the answer from bugix indeed works at some point but I had issues with panning. This is how I fixed panning initially but then noticed it was passing through all the inputs as mono. I've just tested it in an empty project in app delegate and posting whole code that you could just run and see in action.

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var inputNode: AVAudioInputNode { engine.inputNode }
    var inputFormat: AVAudioFormat { inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0) }
    var outputNode: AVAudioOutputNode { engine.outputNode }
    var outputFormat: AVAudioFormat { outputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0) }
    var mainMixerNode: AVAudioMixerNode { engine.mainMixerNode }
    
    let mixerNode: AVAudioMixerNode = .init()


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        
        engine.attach(mixerNode)
        
        let layoutTag: AudioChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Mono
        let layout = AVAudioChannelLayout(layoutTag: layoutTag)!
        let monoFormat: AVAudioFormat = .init(standardFormatWithSampleRate: inputFormat.sampleRate, channelLayout: layout)
       
        engine.connect(inputNode, to: mixerNode, format: inputFormat)
        engine.connect(mixerNode, to: mainMixerNode, format: monoFormat)
        
        try! engine.start()
        
        mixerNode.pan = -0.4
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Also, it didn't work when I tested with 10 input channel audio interface. It was only streaming first two signals. I've tested the same audio interface with Garage Band and it works there. Wonder how Apple does it and the same time doesn't provide us with a straightforward interface to do so. Ideally it should be possible to switch from `AVAudioSession` but it doesn't have that feature. I've looked through all the docs of `AVAudioSession`, `AVAudioEngine` and whatnot but couldn't find anything there.

Comment: I don't know whether this would work, but you might be able to create an `AVAudioUnit` wrapping a matrix mixer (`kAudioUnitSubType_MatrixMixer`) and connect it between the engine's input node and main mixer, and set the cross-point gains appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sounds promising. The only issue is that I’ve never created an audio unit before but would appreciate any documentation to look through and create one. Would also be interesting for me to do that. I’ve also tried to listen to the tap and take float data of the right channel only but could not pass it to the output. Don’t really want to involve player node to be honest.

Comment: My suspicion is that you'll want to use an AVAudioConverter with a AVAudioConverterInputBlock, and just repackage it the way you want. I have a Scarlett Solo here that I might try that on if I have time.

Comment: As I see and if I’m not mistaken it converts to the provided output buffer but how do I propagate it to the output without involving player node and scheduling? I’ll have a better look at the converter tomorrow and also iterested in the result you’ll have if you try it out as well. Thanks for your comment 

Comment: I couldn't connect my Scarlett to my phone, so I can't test it out, but try this:     `engine.mainMixerNode.auAudioUnit.channelMap = [1]`. This should map channel 1 to channel 0.

Comment: Thank you  Will try it out ASAP. Yeah, you’ll need Lightning to USB cable adapter to connect it. Just in case you’ll need to connect it some time you could try this one [USB Adapter for iPad/iPhone]( https://www.amazon.com/dp/B095H7X31P?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share)

Comment: Hmm unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried it in couple of ways: 1) setting `mainMixerNode.auAudioUnit.channelMap = [1]` and connecting input to main mixer node using `inputFormat(forBus: 0)` has the same result. 2) Making the same connection with channel map `[1, 0]` doesn't switch channels and has the same output. 3) Doing the 1st step but by providing `preferredFormat` with `channels: 1` still plays back the channel 0. 4) tried the same steps by involving other mixer in-between input node and main mixer but the results are the same unfortunately :(

Comment: add your channel mapping code to the answer. you should be able to do it by setting the map on the mic bus 1 output scope.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman thanks for the response. I've added the code above under "EDIT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this technical note was the documentation that helped me a lot understand many things. I'm not going to write details myself as it's better if you also read this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2091/_index.html.

Can't post pictures yet so Id suggest checking out the signal flow of AUHAL (in case of iOS it would be AURemoteIO) in the link above.

Apple states:

> When you want to get the audio device's input data, the connection should be **Source:** AUHAL (output scope, element 1) and **Destination** Destination Unit (input scope, input element )

We could skip most of the stuff as `AVAudioEngine` does them on a higher level but let's have a look at **Channel Mapping** section.

We need to make a channel map on `engine.inputNode.audioUnit` which is the closest unit to hardware, hence the lower level than `auAudioUnit` and `avAudioUnit`. `auAudioUnit` in fact might still show that channel map is `[0, 1]` but after we set the property to `audioUnit` we could say that both 0 and 1 would represent 1 or if you've got more channels it could be 2,3 etc. or maybe even [4, 6] under-the-hood whatsoever.

```
typealias AudioChannelCount = UInt32
typealias AudioChannelsResolver = (AudioChannelCount) -> [UInt32]

func mapChannels(
    _ channels: [UInt32],
    inputUnit: AudioUnit,
    format: AVAudioFormat,
    toChannels destinationChannelsResolver: AudioChannelsResolver
) throws {
    var channelMap: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>? = nil
    let numberOfChannels: UInt32 = format.channelCount
    let mapSize: UInt32 = .init(MemoryLayout<Int32>.size * Int(numberOfChannels))
    channelMap = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: Int(mapSize))
    let destinationChannels = destinationChannelsResolver(numberOfChannels)
    
    guard channels.count <= destinationChannels.count else {
        throw MyError.sourceChannelCountIsGreaterThanDestChannelCount
    }
    
    for (index, channel) in destinationChannels.enumerated() {
        guard numberOfChannels > channel else {
            throw MyError.invalidChannelIndexSent
        }
        if channels.indices.contains(index) {
            channelMap?[Int(channel)] = Int32(channels[index])
        } else {
            channelMap?[Int(channel)] = -1
        }
    }
    
    // Assign mutated channel map to audio unit's ChannelMap property
    // When you want to get the audio device's input data, the connection should be:
    // AUHAL (output scope, element 1) -> Destination Unit (input scope, input element)
    // Input - 1, Output - 0
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2091/_index.html
    let status = AudioUnitSetProperty(
        inputUnit,
        kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap,
        kAudioUnitScope_Output,
        1,
        channelMap,
        mapSize
    )
    channelMap?.deallocate()
    
    if status != noErr {
        throw MyError.failedToSetChannelMap
    }
}
```

```
// Could do the same for iOS
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let format = engine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        let desiredFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: format.commonFormat, sampleRate: format.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: format.isInterleaved)
        guard let inputUnit = engine.inputNode.audioUnit else { return }
        
        try! mapChannels(
            [1, 1], // 2nd element doesn't really matter in case we use `desiredFormat` that has 1 channel so could have [1] as well.
// Or you could keep it stereo and both channels would still produce the same output.
            inputUnit: inputUnit,
            format: engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0),
            toChannels: { count in
                .init(0 ..< count)
            }
        )
        
        engine.connect(engine.inputNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: desiredFormat)
        try! engine.start()
    }
}
```

pan works in both cases - using stereo and [1, 1], [0, 0] and such mapping or when using mono format.

`engine.inputNode.pan = -0.7` for example.

And what's most important is that only the channels you set will produce sound. For example, if I've got [1, 1] channel map and I switch the cable from channel 1 into channel 0, I wouldn't get any sound.

## macOS Note

Make sure you enable **Audio input** in **App sandbox** alongside Microphone usage description in Info.plist for engine to produce sound.

Comment: Wow, you literally saved me days of time today I believe. I tried setting the `channelMap` on the `auAudioUnit` with no luck as well, and your code works like a charm. Thank you so much for digging through the old documentation.

Comment: Really great to hear it helped It took months to finally find this out and in this old documentation. It's pretty weird that new docs doesn't say lots of details especially for `CoreAudio`. But anyways, I'm really glad it saved your time and will save others' time as well.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do the channel mapping on the input node like so:

```
engine.inputNode.auAudioUnit.channelMap = [1, 1]
```

Comment: How would you pan it tho? If I set pan, it pans it as if it's still the right channel of the stereo resulting in same volume till 0 and lowering the volume below 0, hence -1 is just silent. I see in Garage Band it's working properly and wonder how Apple does all those stuff. That's so weird and annoying that `AVAudioSession` shows the channels and all their info but doesn't let you select one. It only lets you select datasource.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to unmark this answer as approved :( Apart from having pan issue I've tested it with more than 2 channel input device and it only sets either 2nd channel on both output or 1st one when I try [1,1] or [0,0] but [2,2] and such doesn't work. As I see it always takes streams of all the input channels and passes only 1st and 2nd through in case there's 2 output and if there was 3 or 4 output it would hook 3rd and 4th inputs as well. As I see channel mapping is not what I want but rather selection of specific channel as the only mono input. I know it's possible as it works in GB

Comment: I have finally managed to do it  Reading an outdated Core Audio docs helped me understand much more stuff than the one that’s written in a new docs. I needed to go pretty close to the hardware level and make channel mapping there. AUHAL (in case of iOS RemoteIO) unit needed channel map setting. I’ll post the answer tomorrow Works both on macOS and iOS. Haven’t tested on more than 2 input channel interface but I’m pretty sure it would work there as well. Might test it someday soon maybe.